# Flutter Audio player gives unexpected error

Tags: flutter, audio, audio-player

I am facing one issue, it says .This expression has a type of 'void' so its value can't be used. I am not sure how to resolve this

```
await audioPlayer.play(url) is This expression has a type of 'void' so its value can't be used.
```

```
 playMusic(String url) async {
    if(isPlaying && currentSong != url){
      audioPlayer.pause();
      int result = await audioPlayer.play(url);
      if (result == 1){
        setState(() {
          currentSong = url;
        });
      }
    }else if(!isPlaying){
      // int result = 1;
      int result = await audioPlayer.play(url);
      if (result == 1){
        setState(() {
          isPlaying = true;
        });
      }
    }
    

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `play` method takes a source, and it returns `Future<void>`. therefore, there is no result you can get, but use `await` to finish the future.

```dart
await audioPlayer.play(UrlSource(url));
```

Comment: I still get the same error

Comment: did you remove `int result =`?